# Pandas Python. Top 3 recommended items in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Pandas and I was given a task: for every product find three other products that are most viewed together in the same session

Data frame `viewed.products` looks like:

```
session             products
00b3a43caf4209d2/10 1536
00b3a43caf4209d2/10 42
00b3a43caf4209d2/10 395
00b3a43caf4209d2/10 590
00b3a43caf4209d2/10 2031
00b3a43caf4209d2/11 1309
00b3a43caf4209d2/11 1879
00b3a43caf4209d2/11 1309
00b3a43caf4209d2/11 1879
00b3a43caf4209d2/5  73
00b3a43caf4209d2/5  147
00b3a43caf4209d2/5  585
00b3a43caf4209d2/5  774
00b3a43caf4209d2/5  781
00b3a43caf4209d2/5  1384
00b3a43caf4209d2/5  1463
00b3a43caf4209d2/6  73
00b3a43caf4209d2/6  156
00b3a43caf4209d2/6  1669
00b3a43caf4209d2/6  52
00b3a43caf4209d2/6  73
00b3a43caf4209d2/6  156
```

And desired output would look like (for example):

```
product recommended_products
1536    42 
        73
        2031
42      73
        1309
        156
395     781
        585
        1536
590     147
        42
        781
```

I assume there has to be an aggregate function to group them, but I cannot figure out which one.

Comment: I don't see the pattern of choosing `recommended_products`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use first [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) column `products` on `session` and then use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest.html) if need top `3` values:

```
print (df)
                     products
session                      
00b3a43caf4209d2/10      1536
00b3a43caf4209d2/10        42
00b3a43caf4209d2/10       395
00b3a43caf4209d2/10       590
00b3a43caf4209d2/10      2031
00b3a43caf4209d2/11      1309
00b3a43caf4209d2/11      1879
00b3a43caf4209d2/11      1309
00b3a43caf4209d2/11      1879
00b3a43caf4209d2/5         73
00b3a43caf4209d2/5        147
00b3a43caf4209d2/5        585
00b3a43caf4209d2/5        774
00b3a43caf4209d2/5        781
00b3a43caf4209d2/5       1384
00b3a43caf4209d2/5       1463
00b3a43caf4209d2/6         73
00b3a43caf4209d2/6        156
00b3a43caf4209d2/6       1669
00b3a43caf4209d2/6         52
00b3a43caf4209d2/6         73
00b3a43caf4209d2/6        156
```

```
#if first column is index
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

df = pd.merge(df[['products', 'session']],
              df[['products', 'session']], 
              on='session',
              suffixes=('','_recommended'))

print (df)
     products              session  products_recommended
0        1536  00b3a43caf4209d2/10                  1536
1        1536  00b3a43caf4209d2/10                    42
2        1536  00b3a43caf4209d2/10                   395
3        1536  00b3a43caf4209d2/10                   590
4        1536  00b3a43caf4209d2/10                  2031
5          42  00b3a43caf4209d2/10                  1536
6          42  00b3a43caf4209d2/10                    42
7          42  00b3a43caf4209d2/10                   395
8          42  00b3a43caf4209d2/10                   590
9          42  00b3a43caf4209d2/10                  2031
10        395  00b3a43caf4209d2/10                  1536
11        395  00b3a43caf4209d2/10                    42
12        395  00b3a43caf4209d2/10                   395
13        395  00b3a43caf4209d2/10                   590
14        395  00b3a43caf4209d2/10                  2031
...
...
```

```
print (df.groupby(['session','products'])['products_recommended']
         .nlargest(3)
         .reset_index()
         .drop('level_2', axis=1))

                session  products  products_recommended
0   00b3a43caf4209d2/10        42                  2031
1   00b3a43caf4209d2/10        42                  1536
2   00b3a43caf4209d2/10        42                   590
3   00b3a43caf4209d2/10       395                  2031
4   00b3a43caf4209d2/10       395                  1536
5   00b3a43caf4209d2/10       395                   590
6   00b3a43caf4209d2/10       590                  2031
7   00b3a43caf4209d2/10       590                  1536
8   00b3a43caf4209d2/10       590                   590
9   00b3a43caf4209d2/10      1536                  2031
10  00b3a43caf4209d2/10      1536                  1536
11  00b3a43caf4209d2/10      1536                   590
12  00b3a43caf4209d2/10      2031                  2031
13  00b3a43caf4209d2/10      2031                  1536
...
...
```